# SalesForce dynamic triggers (callbacks)

Tags: salesforce

We are creating a product that allows customers to sign up and somehow "hook up" their SalesForce CRM implementation to it in which we'd like to have it automatically create triggers/callbacks to an endpoint URL we own (and transferring info about the action+details and which customer of ours is triggering it).

For example: when someone enters a lead, a sale, etc. we want our service (custom code elsewhere on HTTP REST endpoint) to be notified.

What is the best approach for this?  I'm a newbie when it comes to SalesForce, just looking for someone to push me the right direction.  I hear "SalesForce Apps" and then there is an API, etc.  I also hear there is an API limit, so is polling a better idea?  Anything else I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you distribute your application or "connector" through the Salesforce App Exchange then you can have an Apex trigger on some SObjects which does an HTTP / REST callout to your service.  Otherwise you could do something similar to how the [Salesforce Webhook Creator](https://www.jamesward.com/2014/06/30/create-webhooks-on-salesforce-com) dynamically generates the necessary Apex and adds it to a Salesforce org (via the Salesforce Tooling REST API).

Comment: but can we dynamically add apex code in salesforce enterprise org.

Comment: Yes, using the Salesforce Tooling API.

Comment: Thank you james for response. Can we create a platform event by using API instead of using UI?

Comment: Yup! Pretty much everything you can do via the UI is available via the API as well.

Comment: Hey james, I have found somewhere we can't use tooling API in production org. Is it true then what should I proceed in production org?

Comment: Oh! I wasn't aware of that restriction.  So you'll have to do this in a Sandbox org and then deploy the changes to production.

Comment: can't we depoly the apex code using metadata api directly from local file system instead of migration from sandbox to production org?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Sorry.